# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Session

Tags: asp.net, linq, session

I am getting an error in this line of code `Session.Linq<Employees>()` :

> " An object reference is required for non-static field,method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Session.get'.

This is my code :

```
 public static object GetData(Dictionary<string, object> tableParams)
        {
            IQueryable<Employees> Employee = Session.Linq<Employees>();
            if (tableParams.ContainsKey("sEcho")) 
            {
                var parser = new DataTableParser<Employees>(tableParams, Employee);
                return parser.Parse();
            }
            return Employee;
        }
```

If I use  `HttpContext.Current.Session.Linq<Employees>();` 
then i get:

> 'System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState' does not contain a definition for 'Linq' and no extension method 'Linq' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState' could be found '

What do  i need to do to get this to work? Am I missing a namespace for Linq with regard to Session?I am using `System.Linq` and `System.Linq.Expression`.

Comment: @jrummell kinda like a `Cup<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding something. What you're trying to do doesn't have anything to do with Linq, at least not in the context of retrieving the object from session.

You need to retrieve the object from session and unbox it:

```
var list = Session["MyList"] as List<int>;
if (list != null)
{
    //the list was found and you can start using it here
}
```